# Why IE developer toolbar stopped working correctly?

Tags: internet-explorer, styles

I have a web app only compatible with ie7. IE developer toolbar has been really helpful, but it stopped working correctly only for a few pages. The feature that no longer works is the "Find by click" option. Precisely the one that speeds up my work.
I started to use another options, like firebug lite, and other js bookmarklets, but they're slower.
(It's not compatible with firefox neither opera, so I can't use Firebug or such plugins)

Is there any known reason for the Developer toolbar to stop working in certain pages?

Comment: I have the same problem, still looking for a solution.  Another annoying problem: sometimes when I add an attribute to toggle with fixes, then want to delete said attribute, it WON'T.  I'm forced to refresh the page, and drill down to the element again... SO ANNOYING.  If you find a solution myself and some coworkers would love to know.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until I discovered the real issue. Until then I tried all sorts of fixes such as enabling/disabling the toolbar addon, messing with IE advanced settings etc - nothing worked.

The solution was to disable the FlashGet addon that I had installed. Try it (if you also happen to have FlashGet) or try disabling one addon at a time and see if you find a culprit. Good luck!